# In unreal engine, what's the difference among "set global time dilation" and "set current time dilation" and "set custom time dilation"?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

what's the different effect of these three functions, thanks!

[image]

Comment: I can not provide an answer for currentTimeDilation, as I'm not sure what class you are calling this from within.

As for Global and Custom time dilation, Matthew Wadstein has some great videos on each here:

Global : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2DtVnOugVY

Custom : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VeA2K1coDVw

Answer (score 3):

Sorry im not programmer but ill explain the easiest way i can. Global Time dilation scales time for all objects in the scene that use time, custom time dilation scales time relative to the global time dilation. For example you are making the Flash game. When running fast the world goes into slow motion. so global time dilation could be 0.1 but flash custom time dilation set to 10